# How to stream audio to VLC?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send mp3-files to VLC (which I open with `#vlc http://localhost:8080`).
But apart from actually sending the mp3 through the network, I don't know how to actually get the file playing.

This is how I do it as of now:

**Setting up sockets**

```
PVTPORT = 1111
PVTSOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
PVTSOCK.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
PVTSOCK.bind(("localhost", PVTPORT))

VLCSOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
VLCSOCK.bind(("", 8080))
VLCSOCK.listen(5)
```

**ClientSide, Sending file-data to PVTSOCK**

```
def send():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    sock.connect(("localhost", 1111))

    f = open(path, "rb")
    ff = f.read(1024)

    while ff:
        sock.send(ff)
        ff = f.read(1024)
```

**Server, Accepting data from PVTPORT and forwarding to VLC**

```
ready = select.select([BCSOCK, PVTSOCK, VLCSOCK, sys.stdin], [], [], 1)
for r in ready[0]:
    if r is VLCSOCK:
            PlayData = ""
            newsock, addr = VLCSOCK.accept()

            while 1:
                data = newsock.recv(1024)
                PlayData += data
                if not data: break

            newsock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
            newsock.send("Content-Type:audio/mp3\r\n")
            newsock.send("\r\n")
            newsock.send(PlayData)

            newsock.close()

        if r is PVTSOCK:

            pvtdata, pvtaddr = PVTSOCK.recvfrom(1024)
            PVTSOCK.connect(("", p))
            PVTSOCK.send(pvtdata)
```